# Set video call time in quickblox

Tags: video, ios7, xcode6, quickblox

In my application I am implementing quickblox api for Audio and Video call. Inside CallViewController I have a timer which is callTimer. Now in my application I want user to make  a call only for limited time. This time length is 30 min only. So while 2 users are on call, I want my timer to tun in reverse. Can somebody tell me. How I should set timer before call starts.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have a call let's say 5 mins then your code should look like this:

(We use Video calling ObjC Chat code sample as a basis http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios)

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark QBRTCClientDelegate

- (void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session connectedToUser:(NSNumber *)userID {

    NSLog(@"Connection with user %@ is established", userID);

   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:600.0
       target:self
       selector:@selector(videoCallTimeOut:)
       userInfo:nil
       repeats:NO];
}

- (void)videoCallTimeOut:(id)timer{
    [self.session hangUp:userInfo];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark QBRTCClientDelegate

- (void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session hungUpByUser:(NSNumber *)userID userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {


}
```